# Mascarar ou retirar e-mail, telefone e urls de uma string PHP

Tags: php

É o seguinte: eu tenho um sistema que usuários postam um anúncio, só que a venda é intermediada pelo sistema, então os usuários não podem postar dados de contato na descrição do anúncio, principalmente números de telefone, e-mails ou urls. Já procurei aqui e em todos os lugares e não acho nada prático que resolva meu problema sem muita gambiarra.

Ex:

"Vendo moto usada, entre em contato 1188889999, moto@usada.com, www.moto.com, http://moto.com"

Como o usuário não pode postar dados de contato, queria fazer algo que mascarassr essas informações automaticamente, que estarão em um string "description" em php.

Seria algo como:

"Vendo moto usada, entre em contato 11****99**, m***@*****.com, www.****.com, http://****.com"

Mais ou menos com a lógica de que se for um celular mostra o DDD e mais ou três números, se for um e-mail apenas a primeira palavra, o @ e o final TLD, se for um URL mostra apenas o final TLD.

Acho que isso é bastante útil pra todos, mas não achei nada que explicasse como fazer. :/

Comment: Uma maneira é usar o wtz118899 que usa o algoritmo xpto@br para saber como obter me ligue no onze noventa e nove oitenta e oito. Brincadeiras a parte use REGEX

Comment: @jean é complicado... rsrs... tem várias formas de burlar. O usuário poderá escrever igual você citou `(ligue: onze, noventa e cinco, zero, quatro...)`... Pode usar espaçamento entre os números... Só com o tempo ele irá conseguir chegar no mais próximo do ideal e mesmo assim, ele terá, de alguma forma, que fazer moderação das postagens, colocar regras de bloqueio de perfil, se necessário ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está querendo esconder os contatos dos usuários "espertões" que querem fazer contato direto com o cliente final sem o seu serviço. Porém, essa proposta de código que vou te mostrar não é a prova de falhas, você precisa sempre estar de olho e refatorar o código da melhor maneira.

Vou mostrar meu código em partes para que fique bem explicado e você possa alterar da melhor forma. Para a explicação, vou utilizar apenas o número de telefone. Mas você pode pegar o **[código completo aqui](https://ideone.com/gwVvth)** ou no final da resposta.

---

**Explicando...**

No seu caso, você precisa primeiro encontrar os tipos de string (email, site, telefone). Para isso eu fiz esses regex:

```
    $string = "Vendo moto usada, entre em contato 1188889999, moto@usada.com, www.moto.com, http://moto.com";

    // captura todos os telefones da string
    preg_match_all('/[0-9\-\(\)]+/', $string, $match_phone);
```

*O que diz esse REGEX?*

```
/[0-9\-\(\)]+/

pegue um conjunto de caracteres que pode ter apenas:

"0-9" - numeros de zero a nove
"("   - colchetes
"-"   - tracinhos (não sei o nome correto)
```

Desta forma, se alguém digitar (11)9999-8888 ou (11)9999999 serão capturados também.

Feito isso, você vai alterar a parte da string capturada e substituir pela antiga.

```
    // altera os telefones encontrados 
    $phones = $match_phone[0];
    foreach($phones as $phone){

        $newPhone = alterar_telefone($phone);
        $string = str_replace($phone,$newPhone,$string);

    }
```

Função `alterar_telefone()`:

```
    function alterar_telefone($phone){

        $num = 0;
        $newStringPhone = "";
        $positions = array(1,2,7,8); // posições que não serão substituidos

        for($x = 0; $x < strlen($phone); $x++){
            if(is_numeric($phone[$x])){
                $num++;
                if(in_array($num,$positions)){
                    $newStringPhone .= $phone[$x];
                    continue;
                }
                $newStringPhone .= "*";
                continue;
            } 
            $newStringPhone .= $phone[$x];
        }
        return $newStringPhone;
    }
```

Neste caso, a string ficou assim:

> Vendo moto usada, entre em contato 11****99**, moto@usada.com,
>   www.moto.com, http://moto.com

Uma forma prática seria substituir todas as partes encontradas por asterisco. Mas não foi isso que você pediu. =)

---

**Código completo**

```
    $string = "Vendo moto usada, entre em contato 1188889999, moto@usada.com, www.moto.com, http://moto.com";

    // captura todos os emails da string
    preg_match_all('/[A-z0-9]+@[A-z0-9\.]+/', $string, $match_email);

    // captura todos os sites da string
    preg_match_all('/(www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)+[A-z0-9\.]+/', $string, $match_site);

    // captura todos os telefones da string
    preg_match_all('/[0-9\-\(\)]+/', $string, $match_phone);



    // altera os emails encontrados 
    $emails = $match_email[0];
    foreach($emails as $email){

        $newEmail = alterar_email($email);
        $string = str_replace($email,$newEmail,$string);

    }


    // altera os telefones encontrados 
    $phones = $match_phone[0];
    foreach($phones as $phone){

        $newPhone = alterar_telefone($phone);
        $string = str_replace($phone,$newPhone,$string);

    }


    // altera os telefones encontrados 
    $sites = $match_site[0];
    $inicioSites = $match_site[1];

    for($s = 0; $s < count($sites); $s++){
        $sewSite = alterar_site($sites[$s], $inicioSites[$s]);
        $string = str_replace($sites[$s],$sewSite,$string);
    }

    echo $string;

    // função que altera o email
    function alterar_email($email){

        $newStringEmail = "";
        $partesEmail = explode("@", $email); // separar em duas partes

        /*
            primeira parte do email
            "moto"

        */

        for($y = 0; $y < strlen($partesEmail[0]); $y++){
            if($y == 0) {
                $newStringEmail .= $partesEmail[0][0];
            } else {
                $newStringEmail .= "*";
            }
        }

        $newStringEmail .= "@"; // adicionando o "@" que foi perdido

        /*

            segunda parte do email
            "usada.com"

        */

        $parts2 = explode(".", $partesEmail[1]);
        for($z = 0; $z < strlen($parts2[0]); $z++){
            $newStringEmail .= "*";
        }

        for($x = 1; $x < count($parts2); $x++){
            $newStringEmail .= ".".$parts2[$x];
        }
        return $newStringEmail;
    }


    function alterar_site($site, $inicio){

        $newStringSite = $inicio;
        $parteInicialSite = explode($inicio,$site);
        $partesSite = explode(".",$parteInicialSite[1]);
        for($x = 0; $x < strlen($partesSite[0]); $x++){
            $newStringSite .= "*";
        }
        for($y = 1; $y < count($partesSite); $y++){
            $newStringSite .= ".".$partesSite[$y];
        }
        return $newStringSite;
    }

    function alterar_telefone($phone){

        $num = 0;
        $newStringPhone = "";
        $positions = array(1,2,7,8); // posições que não serão substituidos

        for($x = 0; $x < strlen($phone); $x++){
            if(is_numeric($phone[$x])){
                $num++;
                if(in_array($num,$positions)){
                    $newStringPhone .= $phone[$x];
                    continue;
                }
                $newStringPhone .= "*";
                continue;
            } 
            $newStringPhone .= $phone[$x];
        }
        return $newStringPhone;
    }
```

**Resultado:**

> Vendo moto usada, entre em contato 11****99**, m***@*****.com,
>   www.****.com, http://****.com

Comment: Muito bom. Isso vai me servir. Vou analisando como vai ficar em produção e aperfeiçoando na medida do tempo. Obrigado!

Comment: Mas acho que tem razão em substituir todas as partes encontradas por *, vou adaptar dessa forma

Comment: @PauloHenriqueRocha sim. Se você colocar para substituir tudo, ficará mais fácil e você só vai ter que se preocupar com o regex.

Comment: Exatamente! Já troquei aqui.